# UIPickerView with NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

In my app, I'm trying to implement a `UIPickerView`, I followed a tutorial and my `UIPickerView` is acting weird. Visually it is empty, but when I scroll in it, my logs show me that is full but with always the same row (I have at least 22 rows).

I receive my datas with `AFNetworking` in a `NSMutableArray` named `collectionTitle`
Here is my code :

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent: (NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.collectionTitle count];
}

- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 30.0;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.collectionTitle objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row   inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    _collecToSend = [self.collectionTitle objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog(@"%@", _collecToSend);
}
```

My class has the delegate and the source for the `UIPickerView` and in my .h I've declared an `IBOutlet` on the `UIPickerView`.

Do I forget something? The result on the screen is empty, but when I scroll the logs show that it is full at least for one row.

Comment: Your code for the pickerView appears to be correct.  Are you receiving your data from AFNetworking after the view has been loaded?  If so, then you are probably needing to reload your pickerView.

Comment: Reloading my pickerView works well ! 
Thank you for helping me ! :)